# php for is not working if i pass the values through variable

Tags: php, xml, for-loop

i am parsing a XML data with `simplexml_load_file()` function and when i display the data using for loop its display correctly from the number i mention to the limit

```
<?php
for($i=10; $i<=20; $i++){
{
 $offer->name;
}
?>
```

but when i declare the values through variable it does not work.

```
<?php
$result_start = $_REQUEST['start'];
$result_limit = $_REQUEST['limit'];


for($i=$result_start; $i<=$result_limit; $i++){
{
 $offer->name;
}
?>
```

one more strange thing is happening here is that the loop is repeating 2 times more. like if i mention the loop from 10 to 20 so it is showing me the values from 10 to 22.

Comment: what is in the $result_start and $result_limit ?

Comment: See what does variables contains. `var_dump($result*);`

Comment: What are those request values when you print them out?

Comment: the request['start'] and request['limit'] contains the number value from start to limit this i am putting it inside the loop

Comment: please show the result of `var_dump($result_start)` and `var_dump($result_limit)` as @CappY said

Comment: here are the var_dump result of both string(2) "50" string(2) "60"

Comment: @HarishKumar The issue is they are strings not numbers?

Comment: @MrD how can i convert them to numbers?

Comment: @HarishKumar See jeroen's answer it is the simplest way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the problem would most easily be solved by casting the user input to integers:

```
$result_start = (int) $_REQUEST['start'];
$result_limit = (int) $_REQUEST['limit'];
```